# Compiling SDL within Adobe Crossbridge's Cygwin

Tags: c++, gcc, cygwin, sdl

[Crossbridge](http://adobe-flash.github.io/crossbridge/) allows you to compile C/C++ programs to target the flash runtime. It comes with its own modified gcc within cygwin. Since SDL only provides developmental zips for VC or mingw, I'm trying to compile SDL within this cygwin environment. However Crossbridge's gcc is version 4.2.1 and according to google searches SDL cannot be compiled with gcc versions higher than 3 inside cygwin. When I run `./configure`, it fails with:

```
*** Your compiler (/cygdrive/c/Users/Tom/Desktop/Crossbridge_1.0.1/sdk/usr/bin/g
cc.exe -jvmopt=-Xmx1G) does not produce Win32 executables!
```

When I just type `gcc` alone, I get:

```
bash: /usr/bin/gcc: cannot execute binary file
```

Does it make a difference if I compile SDL using one compiler (i.e., a lower version of gcc) and attempt to use it with the Crossbridge compiler?

Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Most of SDL isn't going to run on top of Flash -- you'd need Flash-specific graphics backend, Flash-specific audio backend, Flash-specific input backend.  If you just want the portable pieces, try just adding those files to your own project, and ignore the SDL makefiles.

Comment: Yet, they have a successful example of compiling Quake with SDL. What should I do then?

Comment: Hmm, looks like [they already have done (much of) the porting work](http://forums.adobe.com/message/5114547#5114547).  So you need to use the version of SDL from Adobe FlasCC and not from the sdl.org site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked the Crossbridge_1.0.1.zip, cc and gcc maybe are broken link (only 56 bytes?) but the gcc-4 seem to be good.

**edit**

type `gcc-4` as you typed `gcc` from the bash and you'll see the usual *expected* `no input files` gcc's error message, try `gcc-4 -v`

the message `Your compiler does not produce Win32 executables` is given by the fact that whatever you've executed (or has been executed automatically) is using `/cygdrive/c/Users/Tom/Desktop/Crossbridge_1.0.1/sdk/usr/bin/gcc.exe` as your *compiler*, but as you already checked it doesn't work, and if you check it with `ls -l /usr/bin/gcc.exe` you'll see that this is only 56 bytes size, this can't be the real compiler, I guess it probably was a symbolic link to the real compiler, which for some reason isn't working as expected (on linux executing a symlink is as executing the real binary).

I'm not an expert of cygwin, but I guess at some level symlink are supported, reading this [FAQ](http://cygwin.com/faq/faq.html#faq.api.symlinks) make me wonder if some attribute hasn't lost packaging/unpackaging the zip, so that the symlink aren't recognized.

Try to recreate it (it worked for me):

```
cd /usr/bin # change directory
rm gcc.exe # remove the broken link
ln -s gcc-4.exe gcc.exe # re-create the symlink
```

run `gcc` again, should return the `no input files` error as expected.

But this isn't the solution, because probably in the unzipped files there are many broken symlink.

I can't believe Adobe is distributing a broken SDK, so perhaps there's some instruction somewhere about how to properly unzip the SDK preserving the symlinks (maybe unzip have a preserve attribute option? I don't know much about zip sorry.

**edit**

execute the `run.bat` (the bash) and cd to the main directory where you unzipped the SDK (mine is /cygdrive/c/crossbrige)

```
cd /cygdrive/c/crossbrige

for f in $(find ./ -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep '!<symlink>' -l); do attrib +S $f; done
```

this should hopefully fix all the broken symlink, the only side-effect is that any file containing `!<symlink>` will get set the attribute DOS SYSTEM, but cygwin check both this magic string at offset 0 and the S attribute to consider a file as a symlink, so hopefully will not break anything.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean?

Comment: Thanks :) Got it working? I've some more info you maybe interested, let me know.

Comment: Actually, no, I posted this question a month ago. I just gave the bounty to you because your answer makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

I used Alex find/ attribute loop to fix all broken links in my cygwin install. I have no idea why they appeared.

The first attempt failed with messages like:

```
Invalid switch - /usr/lib/terminfo
```

for each file attrib worked on.

Turned out that for my cygwin/Windows combo I had to cd into the directory and execute attrib from there. So the loop content was:

```
do cd $(dirname $f); attrib +S $(basename $f);  done
```